# Deadlock/hanging while reading from a subprocess's stderr in thread - with consideration of KeyboardInterrupt and SystemExit

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, python-multithreading, stderr

I'm using Popen from Python's subprocess module to start a subprocess, and also running another thread to capture its standard error.

I suspect that the Popen context hangs on exit of the context if something is reading from the standard error of the process. This shows the issue:

```py
import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from threading import Thread

def read_from_stderr(proc):
    try:
        c = proc.stderr.read(1)
    except:
        # Swallow for easier to understand trace from main thread
        pass

with Popen(['cat'], stderr=PIPE) as proc:
    print("Starting thread to read stderr")
    t = Thread(target=read_from_stderr, args=(proc,))
    t.start()
    time.sleep(1)

    print("Exiting the context. Will now hang.")
```

And if I hit CTRL+C, I can see in the trace where it stopped:

```
  File "[removed]/subprocess.py", line 1092, in __exit__
    self.stderr.close()
```

To avoid this, I can put a

```py
proc.terminate()
```

in the context, which will allow exit of the context.

But there are complications: `KeyboardInterrupt` and `SystemExit`. They can be raised at more or less *any* point.(?) How can I avoid hanging in the case that that it's raised before any of my own code in the context, so like:

```
raise KeyboardInterrupt()
proc.terminate()
```

Note - I am considering the case where KeyboardInterrupt say is raised before the interpreter gets to any try/except block I can write where it can be caught.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to make sure that the thread is only started once you're in a try/except block that will (attempt to) terminate the process on a BaseException

```py
with Popen(['cat'], stderr=PIPE) as proc:
    print("Starting thread to read stderr")
    try:
        t = Thread(target=read_from_stderr, args=(proc,))
        t.start()
        time.sleep(1)

        print("Simulating a KeyboardInterrupt from CTRL+C")
        raise KeyboardInterrupt()
    except BaseException:
        proc.terminate()
        raise
```

Note from some brief testing I suspect that `Popen` behaves differently depending on the exception it encounters:

- Exception - will wait for the process to end
- Non-Exception BaseExceptions - it will *not* wait for the process to end

But I *think* in both cases it will always try to close the stderr